# Wordpress: Only show authours their own posts when viewing website

Tags: php, wordpress

Question is a little bit out of the box, but any help would be HUGELY appreciated.

I want authors on my website to only be able to see their own posts. Im not talking about in the admin panel, I already have figured that out.  What I want is the author to only be able to see his own posts when viewing the actual website... Public users don't see anything...

I have multiple realtors logging into the website to upload their listings for print.  I want them to be able to review their own listings in a visual form on the website.  But not see others.  Is this possible?

Comment: Yea it's possible but why wordpress.. I feel like you're gonna have to edit the source code for that to work.. then it may or may not get overwritten when wp updates.. idk I'm not that familiar with WordPress.. why don't you use a real cms instead.

Comment: @Pamblam ... WordPress *is* a "real" CMS (in fact, it's the most popular CMS). I humbly recommend you avoid commenting, if you're unfamiliar with it.

Comment: @rnevius that comment was even more irrelevant than mine. And for the record being the most popular does not mean it's the best.

Comment: There's a time and a place for everything and I am familiar enough to know this isn't the time or place for WordPress

Comment: @Pamblam , I completely agree with you. I never called it the "best", and never said this was a good time to use WP (it isn't). But saying WordPress isn't a "real CMS" is a bit misguided...Anyways, it's possible to do what the OP is asking without touching the WP core (again, not saying it's a great idea).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shared any code, which makes this question really difficult to answer. However, assuming you have a fairly standard WP setup, you should be able to use the [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) filter to alter your post query. Here is an equally broad answer:

```
function limit_posts_to_logged_in_author( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && current_user_can('editor') ) {  // Add other checks here...
        // Set the author in the query to the current user
        $query->set( 'author', get_current_user_id() );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'limit_posts_to_logged_in_author' );
```